Fetch Textures From a Collection
Hello everyone who's reading.
I'm trying to create a website where I can mouse scroll through "cards" that are all in a single line, seen with a iso view from the side.
I've set up the scene in THREE.js, but I don't know how to go about having a collection of elements that automatically get used as the card's texture.
To explain better I'd like to:

Create and use an updatable collection of elements (images/videos)
Have each element of said collection get used as the texture for the front face of the boxes
Have the boxes size automatically adapt to the aspect ratio of the image texture
Not having to manually link each texture to each box, but instead each time I insert a new element in the collection, a new card, or box, is created and added to the scene

If someone can help, that would be much appreciated.
Thank you in advance!
Here's the code I have right now:
import './style.css'
import * as THREE from 'three'

// Set up the scene
const canvas = document.querySelector('.webgl');
const scene = new THREE.Scene();
scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xffffff); // Set background color to white

// Create box geometry
const boxGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 0.01);
//Create box material
const boxMaterial = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
  transparent: true,
  opacity: 0.7

});

const numBoxes = 10; // Boxes number
const boxSpacing = 1; // Boxes spacing

// Create boxes mesh
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
  const box = new THREE.Mesh(boxGeometry, boxMaterial);
    box.position.set(0, 0, -i * boxSpacing)  
    scene.add(box);
}

// Add ambient light to the scene
const ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 1); // Soft white light
scene.add(ambientLight);

// Set up the renderer
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas: canvas, antialias: true});
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

// Set up the camera
const zoom = 300; // Adjust this value to control the zoom
const sizes = {
  width: window.innerWidth,
  height: window.innerHeight
}; // Declares sizes value as window sizes

const aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight; // Set aspect ratio to the window's
const camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(
  -sizes.width / zoom,
  sizes.width / zoom,
  sizes.height / zoom,
  -sizes.height / zoom,
  -10,
  1000
);

// const gridHelper = new THREE.GridHelper(100, 100, 0x444444, 0x444444);
// scene.add(gridHelper);

// Camera controls
camera.position.set(2, 2, 5);
camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0)

// Update camera aspect ratio and renderer size when the window is resized
window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
  // Update sizes
  sizes.width = window.innerWidth;
  sizes.height = window.innerHeight;

  // Update camera
  camera.left = -sizes.width / zoom;
  camera.right = sizes.width / zoom;
  camera.top = sizes.height / zoom;
  camera.bottom = -sizes.height / zoom;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

  // Update renderer
  renderer.setSize(sizes.width, sizes.height);
  renderer.setPixelRatio(Math.min(window.devicePixelRatio, 2));
});

// Render the scene
function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
requestAnimationFrame(animate);


<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/vite.svg" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Mirko Pratofiorito</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <canvas class="webgl"></canvas>
    <script type="module" src="/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>

I would have tried something but unfortunately I'm fairly new to JS and don't know where to start doing this.

Why not create a collection of the image URLs and then load the textures and create boxes with the correct aspect ratio for each image and possibly add new elements by defining a function to add a new image URL and create a new box with that texture.  The function loads the new texture, creates a new box with it, and adds the URL to the imageUrls collection as below:
    import './style.css';
    import * as THREE from 'three';
    const canvas = document.querySelector('.webgl');
    const scene = new THREE.Scene();
    scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xffffff); 
    const ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 1);
    scene.add(ambientLight);


    const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ canvas: canvas, antialias: true });
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

    const zoom = 300; // Adjust this value to control the zoom
    const sizes = {
      width: window.innerWidth,
      height: window.innerHeight
    }; 
    const aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight; 
    const camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(
      -sizes.width / zoom,
      sizes.width / zoom,
      sizes.height / zoom,
      -sizes.height / zoom,
      -10,
      1000
    );

 
    camera.position.set(2, 2, 5);
    camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0);

 
    window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
 
      sizes.width = window.innerWidth;
      sizes.height = window.innerHeight;

 
      camera.left = -sizes.width / zoom;
      camera.right = sizes.width / zoom;
      camera.top = sizes.height / zoom;
      camera.bottom = -sizes.height / zoom;
      camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

 
      renderer.setSize(sizes.width, sizes.height);
      renderer.setPixelRatio(Math.min(window.devicePixelRatio, 2));
    });

 
    function createBoxWithTexture(texture, positionZ) {
      const aspect = texture.image.width / texture.image.height;
      const boxGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1 * aspect, 1, 0.01);
      const boxMaterial = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
        map: texture,
        transparent: true,
        opacity: 0.7
     });
      const box = new THREE.Mesh(boxGeometry, boxMaterial);
      box.position.set(0, 0, -positionZ);
      scene.add(box);
    }


    const loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
    const imageUrls = [
      'path/to/image1.jpg',
      'path/to/image2.jpg',
      'path/to/image3.jpg',
  
    ];
    imageUrls.forEach((url, index) => {
      loader.load(url, (texture) => {
        createBoxWithTexture(texture, index * 1.5); 
      });
    });


    function addNewImage(url) {
      loader.load(url, (texture) => {
        createBoxWithTexture(texture, imageUrls.length * 1.5); 
        imageUrls.push(url); // Add the URL to the collection
      });
    }

// Example usage:

addNewImage('path/to/newImage.jpg');

// Render the scene

function animate() {

  requestAnimationFrame(animate);

  renderer.render(scene, camera);

}

requestAnimationFrame(animate);

